# Loop with callback with several parameters (and asynchronous calls)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm using this pattern for writing loops with callback inside ([link](http://www.richardrodger.com/2011/04/21/node-js-how-to-write-a-for-loop-with-callbacks/#.VtWyR-MrIo8)).

```
repeater(i) {
  if( i < length ) {
     asyncwork( function(){
       repeater( i + 1 )
     })
  }
}
repeater(0)
```

My problem is that the callback has several parameters and it's ugly to re-write it every time. I report a kind of pseudo code. Inside the 'repeater' there are other asynchronous calls and the code is practically unreadable.

```
function repeater (index, max, ..., callback) {
  if (index < max) {
    if (index === 1) {
      // Async call to another function
      async () {
        if (index === (max - 1)) {
          callback ();
        } else {
          repeater (++index, max, ..., callback);
        }
      }
    } else if (index === 2) {
      // Async call to another function
      async () {
        if (index === (max - 1)) {
          callback ();
        } else {
          repeater (++index, max, ..., callback);
        }
      }
    }
    // Other cases...
  }
}
```

How can I write the code more readable?

Comment: separate functionality out into separate functions that have callbacks. `if (x) fn1(cb) elseif (y) fn2(cb)` etc. Then, you can factor out the callbacks by using promises, then further simplify things by using loops to express the functionality with a promise chain rather than a recursive function (which will have the added benefit of much better error handling).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Kevin. Your solution could be correct, but I cannot differentiate as you've specified since the 'index' identifies the type of a particular expression. It's not correct conceptually.

Comment: a forEach loop over an array setting up a promise chain (or even a .reduce) would still have an index.

Comment: wait.... you have an array, and for each item in the array, you're doing something completely different? something's not right here...

Comment: I have an AST and, for each node of the AST, I have to perform an action (in my case the async function).

Comment: the same async function for each, just possibly with different data or url? because that would make the giant if/else chain unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, the async function is the same. The only parameter is the type of the node.

Comment: and you're setting the type based on the index? you end up with the same problem. there's gotta be some kind of pattern or better way to decide what "type" each one should be than having an if conditional for each. Kinda defeats the purpose of looping.